# Different align with absolute position

Tags: html, css

i have a `fieldset` and i have set a div to `position: absolute` inside the `fieldset`
but the result is not the same with chrome, mozilla and IE and i notice that chrome add some property like

```
fieldset {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-start: 2px;
-webkit-margin-end: 2px;
-webkit-padding-before: 0.35em;
-webkit-padding-start: 0.75em;
-webkit-padding-end: 0.75em;
-webkit-padding-after: 0.625em;
border: 2px groove threedface;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
min-width: -webkit-min-content;

}
```

how can I make a standard position with chrome, Mozilla and IE ?

Comment: apply `-moz` as a vendor prefix for consistency in mozilla....

Comment: Use jsfiddle so that we can understand.

Comment: Could you describe your problem in a bit more detail? *How* do the results of your code differ between Chrome, Mozilla and IE? Could you show us your code using jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2):

add the css property position : relative to your fieldset.

the div with position absolute, need a parent-element with this property.

```
fieldset {
  position:relative;
}
```

But a Fiddle would be more helpful for your problem.